# Apply aggregate to defined function using R

Tags: r

I'm writing an aggregate function using R, and I need to call inside aggregation defined function `peakdet_new`.

```
peakdet_new <- function(dmx, v, x = NULL)
{
 ....

  if(nrow(data.frame(list(maxtab = maxtab)))== 1)
  {
    data.frame(DataMatrix=c(unique(dmx)), Status=c("OK"))
  } else
  {
    data.frame(DataMatrix=c(unique(dmx)), Status=c("NOK"))
  }
  #list(maxtab = maxtab) #,mintab = mintab)
  #return(maxtab)
  # if(nrow(data.frame(list(maxtab = maxtab)) >= 1))
  #        {
  #          return(print("NOK"))
  #        } else
  #          {
  #          return(print("OK"))
  #        }

}
```

What gives me the output:

```
peakdet_new(DMX_$DataMatrix, DMX_$X, DMX_$Y)
                        DataMatrix Status
1 00003275216311504500-A1820800306    NOK
```

Here is my table

```
DataMatrix  X   Y
00003275216311504500-A1812300356    0.23    30000
00003275216311504500-A1812300356    0.23    30483
00003275216311504500-A1829600367    0.41    30000
00003275216311504500-A1829600367    0.42    30483
```

And the problem is i don't know how to apply `peakdet_new` to aggregate function, below what i've done

```
data.agg <- aggregate(DMX_together[c('X', 'Y')], by = DMX_together['DataMatrix'], FUN = peakdet_new(DMX_together$DataMatrix, DMX_together$X, DMX_together$Y))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'peakdet_new(DMX_together$DataMatrix, DMX_together$X, DMX_together$Y)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Without arguments

```
data.agg <- aggregate(DMX_together[c('X', 'Y')], by = DMX_together['DataMatrix'], FUN = peakdet_new)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "v" is missing, with no default
```

I expect the output of aggregate function:

```
   DataMatrix                         Status
1 00003275216311504500-A1820800306    NOK
2 00003275216311504500-A1829600367    NOK
```

Comment: 1) What is `maxtab`? It is not even a function argument. 2) The function does not use `v` nor `x`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these functions? Could you add a statement stating your goal? Otherwise, the question is now about your function and no particularly clear end goal(at least to me).

Comment: 1)I using `maxtab` output inside `peakdet_new`, but I think your question is not related to  my question, how to apply aggregation to my function `peakdet_new`, btw works perfectly 2)  I was trying to  use v, x(example is up), but it's not help, don't know what to do it

Comment: @NelsonGon I expect the output of aggregate function:

   DataMatrix                         Status
1 00003275216311504500-A1820800306    NOK
2 00003275216311504500-A1829600367    NOK, my goal is using aggregate function and make the calculation, like 'mean' or 'sum` but using my defined function 'peakdet_new' do you need more details? let me know please

Comment: @RuiBarradas just add the whole function `peakdet_new ` hope it helps you :)

Comment: @Parfait, I'm trying to calculate local maxima and minima using the code Matlab from http://www.billauer.co.il/peakdet.html, but my function `peakdet_new `  **doesn't need to be changed**( on my humble opinion) at all it works just fine, this the best what I found, and it detects local max and minimum, but I have a lot of DataMatrix and need to know which of them "OK" or "NOK", but I have 1000 Datamatrix and  should call "peakdet_new(DMX_$DataMatrix, DMX_$X, DMX_$Y)"  1000 times, instead of it I try to do it using aggregate function(still not sure, maybe exist another way to do it)

Comment: Calling outside `aggregate` appears to return your desired result (not your one-row output). See demo: https://rextester.com/JUKUHS66697

Comment: @Parfait, thank you but it's not working:( too simple for that it's not calculated unique DataMatrix, instead see it all as one column, it should be calculated DM by DM, one by one, should I send you the whole dataset? or something else? I'm really out of idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to run operations on a whole data frame, consider calling `peakdet_new` with `by` subsetting by each distinct *DataMatrix*. On the other hand, `aggregate` usually expects a unit level vector sliced by the *by* factors to return an aggregated vector (later binded with grouped factors for a data frame return).

Calling `by` will run operation on each subsetted data frames to build a list (equal to unique values of subset) where you can then `rbind` all elements into a single data frame:

```
df_list <- by(DMX_, DMX_$DataMatrix, function(sub) 
                peakdet_new(sub$DataMatrix, sub$X, sub$Y))

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stacked on advanced uses aggregate function, but your solution works perfect to me, thank you one more time !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem! Great to hear and glad to help.